# php increment letter by number

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, increment

It is pretty simple question but I cannot find best simple solution. I'm trying to render excel where tables will be next to each other in this format:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   | B     | C     | D     | E     | F     | G     | H     |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 |                         TITLE                         |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | IN    | OUT   | NETTO | TEXT  | TEXT  | TEXT  | TEXT  |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3 | value | value | value | value | value | value | value |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

To render title I begin from cell B1 to cell H1 so my first attempt was this:

```
$column = 'B'; // default column number
foreach ($data as $tables) {
    $r = 1; // row number
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column . $r . ':' . $column + 6 . $r, $connector_name);
        $r++;
        // then row with header r++
        // then row with values
        $column++;
        // other table starting in cell I1
    }
}
```

In each table I start in row 1 and I need to move horizontaly so that is why I need to move to others columns by incrementing. The problem is in cell with title where I need cells B1:H1. B1 is simple but then I don't know how to increment column by 6 to get letter H - `$column + 6` doesn't work. Have any idea how to do it with simple solution?

Comment: `B : H` - is fixed or they might change? You are adding `6` in every loop. Why not only `H` instead of that addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

functions ord and chr will help you

```
echo chr(ord($column)+6); // H
```

Note this will work till the Letter // Z only..

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in columns between `A` to `Z`, then @splash58's answer will work.

If you need to use columns beyond `Z`, then I'd recommend using PHPExcel's built-in functions to manipulate column addresses.

```
$column = 'B';
$adjust = 6;
$column = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column) + $adjust - 1);
```

Or something like:

```
$column = 'B';
$adjust = 6;
do {
    $column++;
} while (--$adjust > 0);
```

which will also work with Excel column addresses beyond `Z`

Comment: I have already figured of this excel limit so I used this function eventually. But thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for the correct way to do this using the newer PHPSpreadsheet library:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

$column = 'B';
$adjust = 6;
$column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($column) + $adjust - 1);
```

See also [API Documentation](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Cell-Coordinate.html#method_columnIndexFromString).